# Get PC last last reboot time?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I am able to get PC last reboot time using VBS ([Check Time of Last Boot](https://github.com/alistairmcmillan/WMI-VBScripts/blob/master/Check%20Time%20of%20Last%20Boot.vbs)).

So, Is there any way to get last last previous reboot time? (I mean second reboot time before last boot time)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to filter the event viewer, looking only for 6005/6006 events.

Comment: Even i found same in google. But there is no 6005 and 6006 events exists in my PC event viewer. but when use "TurnedOnTimesView" tool. i am able to see PC shutdown history.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for one computer, you can create a log file by executing a script that write the current time in a task scheduler. Then, use another script to read the log file and get the time value.

If it's for a lot of computer, I don't know how you can do this.